# Simplification of lambda-productions,unary rules and non-useful symbols of a Grammar

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, computation-theory

I know that is not a general question but I would like to know how to do it with an example that I've been already working a bit on it..Once said this:

I have the following Grammar. I tried to simplify it but I'm unsure of its correctness, could someone help me confirming if it's correct or not?

```
S -> BC | lambda
A -> aA | lambda
B -> bB
C -> c
```

If I have to simplify the Grammar I first apply lambda-eliminations where I have something like:

```
S -> BC | B | C
A -> aA | a
B -> bB
C -> c
```

And finally I have to eliminate non-useful symbols:
Firstly I eliminate the ones that are not productive and then the ones that are unreacheable so..

```
S -> BC | bB | C
A -> aA | a
B -> bB  ---> non-productive
C -> c

S -> C | b | C
A -> aA | a --> unreacheable
C -> c
```

Finally I have something like this and I eliminate C because is unnecessary and I also eliminate BC because were eliminated so should be something like:
    S -> b | c

But if i'm honest I don't think that what I've done it's correct but I don't know exactly

Comment: If a non-terminal is non-productive, so is any production which refers to that non-terminal. You can't just pretend it derives an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there might be some problems with your simplification - or I'm having trouble following it. I'll walk through what I would do and you compare to your understanding.

```
S -> BC | lambda
A -> aA | lambda
B -> bB
C -> c
```

I presume the goal is to eliminate as many `lambda` and non-terminal symbols as possible. The first thing to note is that the production `S -> lambda` cannot be eliminated without changing the language; but all other `lambda` productions can be eliminated. We see one other production, so we are assured it can be eliminated. How do we eliminate `A -> lambda`?

We note that `A` is unreachable from `S`, the start symbol. So we can quite easily eliminate `A -> lambda` by eliminating `A` altogether. We arrive at this simpler, equivalent, grammar:

```
S -> BC | lambda
B -> bB
C -> c
```

Now, as our goal is to eliminate non-terminal symbols (we have already eliminated all extraneous `-> lambda` productions) we can look at `S`, `B` and `C`.  We know we need a start symbol, so we might as well keep `S` as it is. `B` can only generate `bB`, which contains non-terminals; and `bB` can never lead to a string of only non-terminals. `B` is unproductive and we can eliminate it. When we eliminate an unproductive symbol, any concatenated term in which it appears must also be eliminated, since the concatenated expression can never arrive at a string of only non-terminals (any concatenated expression in which an unproductive symbol appears is also unproductive):

```
S -> lambda
C -> c
```

Applying our analysis to `C`, we easily see it is as unreachable as `A` was initially and so it can be eliminated in the same way:

```
S -> lambda
```

This grammar is in simplest terms and is minimal in terms of non-terminal symbols and productions for the language `{lambda}`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer very clear and complete!